Google Chrome --remote-debugging-port argument problem (Debian 12)
I have python project, that launches chrome instance with --remote-debugging-port argument and connecting to it using playwright library.
url = "http://localhost:9222/json/version"
subprocess.Popen([CHROME_PATH, f"--remote-debugging-port=9222", url])
websocket_url = get_websocket_debugger_url(url)
with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.connect_over_cdp(websocket_url)

It worked fine on Windows 11, but recently I switched to Debian 12, and it's not working: The Chrome instance is launching, but http://localhost:9222/json/version is giving ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
I tried to run /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 from terminal with and without --no-sandbox argument but result is the same.
It's kinda working only if run the above command with sudo
I tried to use Firefox instead but still got the same issue.

I reinstalled chrome, but the issue was still there. After messing for a bit with ownership, i gave up and decided to restart OS.
For some reason, the issue is gone and remote debugging port is working as expected.
I'm launching chrome with /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222.
The output of ls -la:
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1585 date time /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
UPD. Unfortunately, the issue is still there. It opens websocket for a second and then I got connection refused again.
